# Alternative filmroll js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyone who knows if there is a better alternative for the filmroll js library: http://straydogstudio.github.io/film_roll/ ? I use it because it's almost exactly what I'm looking for: It centers the active image in the middle of the screen and it works great with responsive designs.

The reason I'm looking for an alternative is because it contains a few bugs, which I discovered after one hour usage already:

- It removes the cover from the beginning or end of the slider before it rotates. It would be better to first duplicate the image, so It won't display a white gap at the end of the slider while rotating. Anyways, I used a dirty fix by just loading the covers multiple times so it contains more images than what fits on the screen.
- Every div contains a hardcoded width, which changes so now and then, because I use a bigger size for the active image. The problem is it doesn't always recover the width correctly of the parent div, so it will show white gaps between the images.
- With touchSwipe enabled it is very very buggy.
- I can't duplicate the slider multiple times with the same classname.

It truly is a great concept, only those bugs are quite bothering me. So before I start making adaptions, I'm just curious: Does anyone know a library which does exactly the same? Or almost the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Iscroll as an alternative

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5

Comment: Thanks, looks very good. I still got a lot of code to write to make it work, but I guess this would be a good start.